# Image is not aligned right to popup block

Tags: html, css, alignment

Hi,

I have created a popup which has a close button right most to the edge of that popup. I tried to align that image by putting :

```
position:absolute;
right:0px;
top:0px;
```

but its not aligning properly..Can any one help.!!!!

Here is my piece of code..

```
 <!DOCTYPE>
    <html>
     <head>
      <title> New Document </title>     
 <style>      
      div.irmGraphPopup{
        border:10px solid black;
        width:1000px;
        height:500px;
        position:absolute;
       }

      div.irmGraphPopup span:{
        position:absolute;
        right:0px;
        top:0px;
      }
       </style>
     </head>

     <body>
      <div class="irmGraphPopup">
          <span> <img src="round_black_close2.png" alt="Close"/></span>
       </div>

     </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a typo:

```
div.irmGraphPopup span{
   position:absolute;
   right:0px;
   top:0px;
}
```

Remove the :

Comment: Dude, I want to set negative values to top and right css rules. I would like to put that image on top of the right top corner on the border of popup.But some part of the image is hidden under border of the popup if I put -10px to right and left offset...Can u tel me the reason.. Even I tried by putting z-index:99999; , but it didnt help me out....

Comment: It's an element within it parent, so if 7you give it negative margin, it will overflow its container. To achieve what you want you need a different approach, ill code something up for you.

Comment: @Rama Rao M, try this - http://jsfiddle.net/xGQcN/

Comment: There's a [campaign to clean up Stack Overflow](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/167342) by removing these typo-related questions, we could really use your help! Would you mind pitching in a little by casting a close vote on this question?

Answer (score 1):

its your css selector

```
 <!DOCTYPE>
    <html>
     <head>
      <title> New Document </title>     
 <style>      
      div.irmGraphPopup{
        border:10px solid black;
        width:1000px;
        height:500px;
        position:absolute;
       }

      #myid{
        position:absolute;
        right:0px;
        top:0px;
      }
       </style>
     </head>

     <body>
      <div class="irmGraphPopup">
          <span id=myid> <img src="round_black_close2.png" alt="Close"/></span>
       </div>

     </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Woks for me if you fix the typo. It should be

```
div.irmGraphPopup span {
```

not

```
div.irmGraphPopup span:{
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the position element of div.irmGraphPopup to relative. Then the span is positioned **absolutely** in **relation** to the div.  Also get rid of the colon after the span (typo?)

```
div.irmGraphPopup{
        border:10px solid black;
        width:1000px;
        height:500px;
        position:relative;
}
```